# NO_PUBKEY error in google cloud debian packages update

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google

I have a couple of Google Clouds compute instances (US, Germany, Australia)

While doing

```
apt-get update
```

today I get:

```
> Get:10 http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt
> google-cloud-packages-archive-keyring-stretch InRelease [3,876 B]
> Err:6 http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk-stretch InRelease
>   The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 6A030B21BA07F4FB 
> Err:7 http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt google-compute-engine-stretch-stable InRelease   
>   The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 6A030B21BA07F4FB 
> Err:10 http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt google-cloud-packages-archive-keyring-stretch InRelease   
>   The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 6A030B21BA07F4FB
```

On all of them.
Is there anything I need to do, or is this a corruption on Google packages?

Thanks

Yves

Answer (score 45):

If you followed the guide here: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install#deb and used the `signed-by` option, then you need to provide apt-key with the `--keyring` option:

```
curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo apt-key --keyring /usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg add -
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer. It's the only thing that actually fixed it for me.

Answer (score 24):

Found the issue here:
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/known-issues#keyexpired

So you just need to run this before to apt-get update:

```
curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
```

Answer (score 0):

Modern Debian 10 uses alternative scheme for registering package signing keys, following Ansible script demonstrates it:

```
- name: Add GCP Apt signing keys.
  ansible.builtin.apt_key:
    id: "{{ item }}"
    url: https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg
    keyring: /usr/share/keyrings/gcp-deb-keys.gpg
  loop:
    # Rapture Automatic Signing Key, expires: 2023-03-02
    - "7F92E05B31093BEF5A3C2D38FEEA9169307EA071"
    # gLinux Rapture Automatic Signing Key, expires: 2022-12-04
    - "59FE0256827269DC81578F928B57C5C2836F4BEB"

- name: Add GCP repo for Cloud SDK.
  apt_repository:
    filename: "gcp-google-cloud-sdk"
    repo: "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/gcp-deb-keys.gpg] https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk-buster main"
    state: present
# Contains: google-compute-engine-oslogin, google-osconfig-agent
- name: Add GCP repo for Compute Engine setup.
  apt_repository:
    filename: "gcp-compute-engine"
    repo: "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/gcp-deb-keys.gpg] https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt google-compute-engine-buster-stable main"
    state: present
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me (in 2023)

```
echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg] https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk main" | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud-sdk.list
curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | apt-key --keyring /usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg add -
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y google-cloud-sdk
```

This was originally a line in a dockerfile, so you may need to add some sudos to the commands above.

The oneline dockerfile instruction is:

```
RUN echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg] https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk main" | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud-sdk.list && curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | apt-key --keyring /usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg add - && apt-get update && apt-get install -y google-cloud-sdk
```

Answer (score 0):

The only command that ended up working for me on Ubuntu 22.04.2 was adapted from this GitHub comment: https://github.com/kubernetes/release/issues/1982#issuecomment-1415573798

```
# Use of gpg dearmor and dd required to get the key in the expected format
curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | 
  gpg --dearmor | sudo dd status=none of=/usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg

# Reference the keyring as documented if not done already
echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg] https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk main" | 
  sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud-sdk.list

# Now update should run successfully
sudo apt-get update
```